# Own simple webserver doesn't send the page

Tags: c, sockets

I've wrote a little webserver that just needs to send a html page or an error page to the browser. Just for practicing my new socket knowledge.

In this program I was trying to use the select method to handle more then 1 request.

The program accepts my connection but then nothing happens... firefox still keeps loading the file, but the file never shows up and the program doesn't do anything (it isn't crashed though.).

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <time.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib" )
#define BUFFSIZE 512
#define PORT "9001"
#define MAXCONNECTIONS 10

char * getPath(char * input, int var, char result[]);
void sendHeader(char * ext, char *path, int socketDescr, int code);
void sendBody(char * ext, char *path, int socketDescr, int code);


int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    struct timeval tv;  // timeinterval for request (should arrive in less than 2seconds)
    fd_set master;      // keeps track of all open file descriptors + listener
    fd_set read_fds;    // list of file descriptors to read from
    int fdmax;          // max file descriptor number
    int listener;       // file descriptor on socket
    int newfd;          // new client file descriptor
    struct sockaddr_storage clientaddr; // client address
    socklen_t addrlen;  // length of address
    char clientIP[INET_ADDRSTRLEN]; // client ip-address (ipv4)
    char buffer[BUFFSIZE]; // buffer for request
    char request[BUFFSIZE]; // buffer for request
    int recvbytes;      // amount of bytes received
    int yes = 1;        // reuse address
    int i,rv;
    struct addrinfo serverinfo, *socketlist, *sock;

    char result[BUFFSIZE];
    char  * path;
    char * extension;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsaData) != 0) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Set up time interval
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    // Clean up file descriptor sets
    FD_ZERO(&master);
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);

    // Get a socket and bind for listening
    memset(&serverinfo, 0, sizeof(serverinfo));
    serverinfo.ai_family = AF_INET;
    serverinfo.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // TCP
    serverinfo.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // we search a socket on our side (server side) for listening

    if((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL,PORT,&serverinfo,&socketlist)) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Server: %s\n",gai_strerror(rv));
        exit(1);
    }

    // loop trough sockets
    for(sock = socketlist; sock != NULL; sock = sock->ai_next)
    {
        listener = socket(sock->ai_family, sock->ai_socktype, sock->ai_protocol);
        if(listener < 0)
        {
            continue; // not correct socket
        }
        setsockopt(listener,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int));
        if(bind(listener, sock->ai_addr, sock->ai_addrlen) < 0)
        {
            closesocket(listener);
            continue; // could not bind to socket
        }
        break;
    }

    // if could not get socket
    if(sock == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Server: %s\n","Could not bind to socket");
        exit(2);
    }

    // free up list, we have the socket
    freeaddrinfo(socketlist);

    // listen on socket
    if(listen(listener,MAXCONNECTIONS) < 0)
    {
        perror("Server: listen");
        exit(3);
    }

    // add listener to master set
    FD_SET(listener,&master);
    fdmax = listener;
    fprintf(stdout,"Server: %s\n","Waiting for connections...");

    for(;;)
    {
        read_fds = master;
        if(select(fdmax+1,&read_fds,NULL,NULL,&tv) < 0)
        {
            perror("Server: select");
            exit(4);
        }

        // run through existing connections to see if request has arrived
        for(i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++)
        {
            if(FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds))
            {
                if(i == listener)
                {
                    // we have a new connection
                    addrlen = sizeof clientaddr;
                    if((newfd = accept(listener,(struct sockaddr*)&clientaddr,&addrlen)) < 0)
                    {
                        perror("Server: accept");
                        exit(5);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FD_SET(newfd,&master);
                        if(newfd > fdmax)
                        {
                            fdmax = newfd;
                        }
                        fprintf(stdout, "Server: New connection from %s on socket %d\n",inet_ntop(clientaddr.ss_family, &(((struct sockaddr_in*)((struct sockaddr*)&clientaddr))->sin_addr), clientIP, sizeof(clientIP)),newfd);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // handle data from request
                    if((recvbytes = recv(i,buffer,BUFFSIZE-1,0)) <= 0)
                    {
                        if(recvbytes == 0) //connection closed
                        {
                            fprintf(stdout,"Server: socket %d goodbye\n",i);
                        }
                        else //request error [BAD REQUEST]
                        {
                            perror("Server: recv");
                        }
                        closesocket(i);
                        FD_CLR(i,&master);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        recvbytes = recv(i, buffer,BUFFSIZE-1 , 0);
                        if(recvbytes > 0)
                        {
                            buffer[recvbytes]='\0';
                            strcat(request,buffer);
                        }
                        fprintf(stdout,"Server: request received:\n");
                        printf("%s", request);

                        //Get path
                        path = getPath(request,0, result);
                        if(strcmp(path,"error") != 0)
                        {
                            extension = getPath(request,1,result);
                            if(strcmp(extension,"error") != 0)
                            {
                                // send file 200
                                sendBody(extension,path,i,200);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // send code 400
                            sendBody("html","400.html",i,400);
                        }

                        closesocket(i);
                        FD_CLR(i,&master);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Gives path, extension of file or error
char * getPath(char * input, int var, char result [])
{
    char * pch;
    char str[BUFFSIZE];
    strcpy(str,input);

    pch = strtok(str,"\r\n");
    pch = strtok(pch," ");

    if(strcmp(pch,"GET") != 0)
    {
        strcpy(result,"error");
        return result;
    }

    pch = strtok(NULL," ");
    if(var == 0)
    {
        strcpy(result,pch);
        return result; 
    }
    pch = strtok(pch,".");
    pch = strtok(NULL,".");
    if(var == 1)
    {
        strcpy(result,pch);
        return result;
    }

    return 0;
}

//Send header
void sendHeader(char * ext, char *path, int socketDescr, int code)
{
    FILE * fp;
    int fileSize = 0;
    char fileSizeChar[32];
    char * header;
    char * status;
    char * contenType;
    char * contentLength;
    char * msg;

    if((fp = fopen(path, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file %s\n",path);
        return;
    }
    //Get filesize
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    fileSize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    fclose(fp);

    //Create header response message
    header = "HTTP/1.0 ";

    if(code == 200)
        strcpy(status,"200");
    else if(code == 400)
        strcpy(status,"400");
    else if(code == 404)
        strcpy(status,"404");

    if(strcmp(ext,"html") == 0)
        strcpy(contenType," text/html\n");

    //create and send header
    strcat(msg,header);
    strcat(msg,status);
    strcat(msg,contenType);
    strcat(msg,contentLength);
    strcat(msg,fileSizeChar);

    send(socketDescr, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
}

//Sending data like, pictures, zip, html pages... or an error html page
void sendBody(char * ext, char *path, int socketDescr, int code)
{
    FILE * fp;
    int fileSize = 0;
    int sendBytes = 0;
    int resultRead;
    int resultSend;
    char buffer[1000];

    if((fp = fopen(path, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open file %s\n",path);
        if(code == 400)
        {
            printf("Error page 400 doesn't exist.\n");
            return;
        }
        if((fp = fopen("404.html","r")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error page 404 doesn't exist.\n");
            return;
        }
        strcpy(ext,"html");
        strcpy(path,"404.html");
        code = 404;
    }

    sendHeader(ext,path,socketDescr,code);

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    fileSize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    while(sendBytes < fileSize)
    {
        fseek(fp,sendBytes,SEEK_SET);
        resultRead = fread(buffer,sizeof buffer[0],1000,fp);
        resultSend = send(socketDescr,buffer,resultRead,NULL);
        sendBytes +=resultSend;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

The only line that shows up is " Server: New connection from %s on socket  ".

Can someone help me please?

Kind regards,

Comment: I saw the `#include <winsock.h>` part and thought "Ah, that's why!"...

Comment: Sorry for the large code. Yeah I know I'm a windows user :D.

Comment: Something strange is going on with the calls to `recv`.  The first one is in the `if` statement.  Then, if there is no error, the data is thrown away since `recv` is called once more, but without error checking.

Comment: I changed that, was my bad but then when asking for a page the server gives me access violation on if((recvbytes = recv(i,buffer,BUFFSIZE-1,0)) <= 0)

Comment: You might like to run your server in a debugger and see what's actually happening.

Comment: Parts of this code seem to assume that the entire request arrives at once:  on every loop through the fds `getPath` is called.  But the request is possibly incomplete: `MSG_WAITALL` is not used.  But then there's a call to `strcat` to concatenate bits of the request as they arrive.  However, this `request` buffer is shared between all sockets.  You can either assume requests are short, and receive them entirely (using the `MSG_WAITALL` flag to `recv`), or have a per-fd buffer where you concatenate pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Too much info here for a comment - but this may help others with your problem:

I compiled and ran your code and when I look in the debugger it is and the server is blocked waiting for input I think

```
                recvbytes = recv(i, buffer,BUFFSIZE-1 , 0);
```

Console

> Server: Waiting for connections... 
>   Server: New connection from
>   127.0.0.1 on socket 120 Server: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on socket 124

my buffer has (440 chars):

- buffer  0x0028f668 "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:9001\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\nAccept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6\r\nAccept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3\r\nCookie: plushContainerWidth=100%25; plushNoTopMenu=0\r\n\r\nÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ...

and My Browser has waiting.

I sent another request through and it crashed - so I suspect that the recv is blocking (Look at the options you can use on the call) possibly waiting for a full buffer.

At this point I get a crash in GetPath because there was no data in request, and this was the case because the recv call returned 0 bytes.

Hope this helps.